# Overriding the section row data in expand table view, when there are multiple sections of same type

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have created a Collapsible table view using sections and which in-turn contains a single row.Initially tableview has 4 sections and My last section has ability of adding 3rd section multiple times when the user taps on the last.

Now am facing an issue when the user expands the section and enters the data and after that when he expands the dynamically added section the same data appearing in the newly added only also and it is vice-versa if the user modifies any data on newly added section row then it is overriding the existing content in 3rd section too.

**The code is as follows:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

  //creating section items where 1st three are static and the third section will add dynamically when the last section tapped by the user.
  tableMenuItems = [["sectionHeader": "Ship To","isCollapsed":true, "image" : "shipto.png" ],
                    ["sectionHeader": "Ship From","isCollapsed":true,"image" : "shipfrom.png"],
                    ["sectionHeader": "Package Details","isCollapsed":true,"image" : "package.png"],
                    ["sectionHeader": "Add a Package","isCollapsed":true,"image" : "newaddpack.png"]]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableMenuItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    let isCollapsed = tableMenuItems[section]["isCollapsed"] as! Bool
    return isCollapsed ? 0 : 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{    
   let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 120))
   view.tag = 200 + section
   view.backgroundColor = .white
   let prefixIconBtn = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 12, y: 20, width: 48, height: 48))
   prefixIconBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: tableMenuItems[section]["image"] as! String), for: .normal)
   prefixIconBtn.tag = 500 + section
   prefixIconBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector (displayOrHideSection(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

   let titleLabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 75, y: 18, width: 250, height: 60))
   titleLabel.tag = 100 + section

   let sectionHeaderBtn = UIButton.init(frame: titleLabel.frame)
   sectionHeaderBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector (displayOrHideSection(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   sectionHeaderBtn.tag = section

   titleLabel.font = UIFont(name:"SFUIText-Regular", size: 20.0)

   let plusOrMinus = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 340, y: 20, width: 38, height: 38))
   plusOrMinus.tag = section
   plusOrMinus.addTarget(self, action: #selector (displayOrHideSection(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   titleLabel.text = tableMenuItems[section]["sectionHeader"] as? String

   if titleLabel.text == "Add a Package" {
      plusOrMinus.isHidden = true   
   }

   if tableMenuItems[section]["isCollapsed"] as! Bool == true
   {
      plusOrMinus.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "Log_plus"), for: .normal)
     tableMenuItems[section]["isCollapsed"] = true
   }
  else
  {
     plusOrMinus.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "Log_minus"), for: .normal)
     tableMenuItems[section]["isCollapsed"] = false
  }

  view.addSubview(titleLabel)
  view.addSubview(prefixIconBtn)
  view.addSubview(sectionHeaderBtn)
  view.addSubview(plusOrMinus)

  plusOrMinus.tag = section

  let seperatorLine = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 78, y: 78, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 1))
  seperatorLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
  view.addSubview(seperatorLine)    
  return view
}

@objc func displayOrHideSection( _sender : AnyObject)
{       
    let section = _sender.tag        
    if section == 0
    {
        if tableMenuItems[0]["isCollapsed"] as! Bool == false
        {
            tableMenuItems[0]["isCollapsed"] = true
        }
        else
        {
            tableMenuItems[0]["isCollapsed"] = false
        }
    }

    else if section == 1
    {
        if tableMenuItems[1]["isCollapsed"] as! Bool == false
        {
            tableMenuItems[1]["isCollapsed"] = true
        }
        else
        {
            tableMenuItems[1]["isCollapsed"] = false
        }
    }
    else if section == 2
    {
        if tableMenuItems[2]["isCollapsed"] as! Bool == false
        {
            tableMenuItems[2]["isCollapsed"] = true
        }
        else
        {
            tableMenuItems[2]["isCollapsed"] = false
        }
    }        
    else if section! >= 3
    {                       
        if section!  > 502

        {
            // to delete a dynamically added  package
            tableMenuItems.remove(at: section! - 500)               
        }
        else if section!  < 502              
        {               
            // adding a new package section when the user taps on Add a package section(Last section)

        let titleLabel  = self.logTable?.viewWithTag(100 + section!) as! UILabel

        print(titleLabel)

        // when add a package tapped

        if titleLabel.text == "Add a Package"
        {
            tableMenuItems.insert(["sectionHeader": "Package Details","isCollapsed":true,"image" : "package.png"], at: tableMenuItems.count-1)
        }

      // when plus or minus button tapped on Add a package
      else
      {

        if tableMenuItems[section!]["isCollapsed"] as! Bool == false
        {
             // expanding section

             tableMenuItems[section!]["isCollapsed"] = true
             tableMenuItems[section!]["image"] = "package.png"


        }
        else
        {
             // collapsing section

            tableMenuItems[section!]["isCollapsed"] = false
            tableMenuItems[section!]["image"] = "newdeletepackage.png"             
        }

        }

      }
    }
 logTable!.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Why don't you have custom model as `struct` instead of `Dictionary`?

Comment: Followed some tutorial and implemented the same dude.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.Thank you folks.